# Generating PDF and attaching it with email in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am building an application in Windows Phone 7 where i need to send data from a form to web service. On successfull submission of the Form i want to generate a pdf of the data submitted and i want to send an email which should contain the PDF as an attachment. Is there any nice tutorial for doing it. Please help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959546/how-do-i-send-an-email-from-a-windows-phone-8-application

Comment: @crea7or Hey frnd i know sending email but i wanted to know if there is any possible way to attach a pdf in my mail

Comment: There are solutions to attach the files. Read the answers.