# ShareMediaTask for WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I saw for Windows phone 8 there is [ShareMediaTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.sharemediatask), is there something analog for WinRT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think, it would be available. Microsoft recommends to use share charm. WinRT has [DataTransferManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datatransfermanager) class for sharing the data.

[Mixed Media – Audio & Video – Windows Store vs. Windows Phone 8](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2013/03/08/mixed-media-audio-amp-video-windows-store-vs-windows-phone-8.aspx)

[Sharing content source app sample from MSDN](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sharing-Content-Source-App-d9bffd84)

Answer (score 1):

DataTransfer is not working for Windows Phone I tried it Don't know why mentioned in MSDN that supported OS is Windows Phone 8.please see it.
[Sharing from Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13589448/sharing-from-windows-phone-8)