# Sharing with DataTransferManager Title in Body (e.g. Messaging)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am using `DataTransferManager` to implement sharing within my WindowsPhone 8.1 app, it works fine although I have a small annoyance that I haven't been able to sort out.

I am populating `request.Data.Properties.Title` but when I share to Messaging, where there is nowhere to put a title, it puts it in the body of the message. Is there a way around this?

I have tried not supplying the Title property, or supplying an empty string, but that stops the share menu displaying at all.

EDIT: here is the code I am using:

```
private void ShareTextHandler(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    DataRequest request = e.Request;
    request.Data.Properties.Title = "Generated Draw";

    request.Data.SetText(CreateDraw.formatDrawForSharing(currentDraw));
}
```

Comment: No-one? If it can't be done then someone please say so...

Answer (score 0):

You mean the normal text message right? I don't think you can have a title for that.

```
SmsComposeTask smsComposeTask = new SmsComposeTask();

smsComposeTask.To = "thenumber";
smsComposeTask.Body = "Sometext here";
smsComposeTask.Show();
```

Did you try using these specific `tasks` or `launchers`?

[Sharing from Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13589448/)

Comment: Yeah I do, although I don't want to be limited to just SMS. I have added the code I wrote in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

The `request.Data.Properties.Title` property display or not display, it depends on the **share target**.
For example, if you share with **Messaging**, it will display **Title + Content** together. But if you share with **E-Mail**, the Title will be displayed in the **Mail Subject**.

Comment: I have added the code to the original post, with that code, if I select Messaging I get "Generated Draw" immediately followed by the string returned by `CreateDraw.formatDrawForSharing(currentDraw)`, all in the body of the message .

Comment: Oh, I see. In DataTransferManager, the Title and Text must not be empty. Maybe you can set the title to a WhiteSpace.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Chris. I Don't think you can have a title for a message.
Instead of the **Data Transfer Manager** you can try the **ChatMessage** though.

```
 using Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat;

var chatMessage = new ChatMessage();
chatMessage.Body = "Sometext here";
await ChatMessageManager.ShowComposeSmsMessageAsync(chatMessage);
```