# Sharing links from WP8 app

Tags: windows-phone-8, sharing

I have done everything exactly as in [How to share text and links from a Direct3D app for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206982%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):

```
e->Request->Data->Properties->Title = "Share Text Title";
e->Request->Data->Properties->Description = "Share Text Description";
e->Request->Data->SetText("Main text");
e->Request->Data->SetUri(ref new Uri("http://msdn.microsoft.com"));
```

but on share screen (and on result webpage) I can only see two fields of four:

[image]

As you can see, description and text are missed. What's wrong and who's guilty?

Comment: Did you try using the `Tasks/Launchers`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13589448/

Comment: @anonshankar That's about C#. I have native C++ app.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing is wrong, this is the expected behaviour. You have no guarantee of how the data you supply is used of if it is used at all.

It is up to the target application to use the content you provide in the most appropriate way for it's scenario. Currently (WP8.1 Build 12397) in the case of the messaging app if you only set the text and the title on the DataPackage it will display both of those however if you set a url as well it will display the title and the url but not the text.

The guidance is to give as many representations of the data as possible however if you know the user may want to share the text instead of both the link and text you might want to consider giving the user the option before invoking the share UI.

Comment: Can you share the link to the documentation that specifies what you told? Thanks in advance

Comment: It was in one of the build sessions last year, this one i think: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/2-520 However seeing as build is right around the corner you may aswell wait that.