# Windows phone 8 - NotSupportedException in DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am trying to implement **share functionality** in windows phone 8 where if a user long press on an image it shows a context menu with default share options (including installed applications through which we can share on Phone). For that I am using **DataTransferManager** Class and getting System.NotSupportedException - Specified method is not supported. when I am calling the below event

```
private void Image_Hold(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
        {                         
            // get the DataTransferManager object associated with current window
            **var dataTransferManager = DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView();**

            // register event to handle the share operation when it starts
            dataTransferManager.DataRequested -= OnDataRequested;
            dataTransferManager.DataRequested += OnDataRequested;

            // show the charm bar with Share option opened
            DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI();
        }
```

I am referring [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datatransfermanager.getforcurrentview.aspx) for the same which says minimum requirement is Windows Phone 8 and this API will be supportive only in native apps.

Please, let me know any way to resolve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13589448/sharing-from-windows-phone-8